# 'Open in Google Maps' button text is not clear in lightning-map component because of branding theme

Tags: lightning-map

I am using lightning-map component , the footer button 'Open in google maps' text is not seen because of the brand theme we use. Unfortunately we cant change the branding theme. Is there a way to set the text color of 'Open in google maps' button ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) to change the style of the Button. I have tried with the below example and it is working. Change the colors as per your requirement.

*CSS*

```
.my-css {
    --slds-c-button-brand-color-background: #9050e9; 
    --slds-c-button-brand-color-background-hover: #5a1ba9;
    --slds-c-button-brand-color-border: #9050e9; 
    --slds-c-button-brand-color-border-hover: #5a1ba9;
    --lwc-brandTextLink: #ffffff;
    --lwc-brandTextLinkActive: #ffffff;
  }
```

HTML

```
<lightning-map class="my-css"....
```

*Output*

[image]